# Ionic ion-radio css :Selected

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I got a problem with my css in ionic...

I want to change the css, when a radiobutton is clicked. as shown below.

```
  [type=radio]:checked + ion-icon {
      background-color: $primaryColor;
      color: white;
      font-size: 45px;
  }
```

The above css works on for the html tag  but in ionic you have a tag called ion-radio. So is there a way to achieve the same, but with the radio button from ionic?

```
  ion-radio:checked + ion-icon {
      background-color: $primaryColor;
      color: white;
      font-size: 45px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I noticed from the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio), once an `ion-radio` is checked, it gets the class `radio-checked`.

Inspect your elements, don't they get this class too once they're checked?

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but i want to change the ion-icon. And this tag is outside the ion-radio button.

Comment: It's hard answering without seeing the code. I thought maybe `.radio-checked + ion-icon` would work.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by adding a class if a specific radiobutton is checked.

HTML:

```
<ion-icon [ngClass]="{'active': (gender == 'Female')}" name="female"></ion-icon>
```

CSS:

```
 /* CHECKED STYLES */
  ion-icon.active {
      background-color: $primaryColor;
      color: white;
      font-size: 45px;
  }
```